# Copy directory of current window to clipboard on Mac

Tags: scripting, applescript

Is it possible to copy the full directory of the current active window on Mac?

e.g. say I have example.txt open in Sublime Text, can I execute an Apple Script that will grab the full path of that file? (without going to Finder).

The result would be that /Users/Bob/Dropbox/example.txt would then be in my clipboard.

Comment: +1 this would be great to have, currently I have to paste into a Terminal, and recopy.

Comment: One comment on this post details an Apple Script…

http://superuser.com/questions/371513/how-to-tell-full-path-of-file-on-mac

…But I can't get this to work… tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
    set the clipboard to path of document 1 as text
end tell

Comment: I got http://i.stack.imgur.com/Vhv9D.png working. If you are having trouble, I can send a link to the `.workflow`.

Comment: Hey Alex, if you have a link that would be great.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ca93fjhebqzm1sx/uusCpufqwY

Comment: Do you have it working in anything outside of Finder? It only shows up as a Finder service for me :-/

Comment: no I don't have it working. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [assign a shortcut to a script](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943) like this:

```
try
    tell application (path to frontmost application as text)
        set the clipboard to (path of document 1) as text
    end tell
on error
    try
        tell application "System Events" to tell (process 1 where frontmost is true)
            value of attribute "AXDocument" of window 1
        end tell
        do shell script "ruby -rcgi -e 'print CGI.unescape ARGV[0][16..-1]' " & quoted form of result
        set the clipboard to result
    end try
end try
```

The first method didn't work with Preview, TextMate 2, Sublime Text, or iChm, and the second method didn't work with Acorn.

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks Lauri. I've set this to execute on a keyboard shortcut using Keyboard Maestro, and it works a treat.